# select min date from max id from table

Tags: mysql, max, min

I'm new here but I have one little big problem.

I have this table (for example)

```
id | client| date
------------------------------
 7 | v1    | 2015-05-20
 6 | v1    | 2015-05-20
 5 | v1    | 2015-05-01
 4 | v1    | 2015-03-05
 3 | v2    | 2015-02-02
 2 | v3    | 2015-01-30
 1 | v1    | 2015-01-01
```

I need the first row from the last client, this way is client v1, but when I select the min date the result is v1 from id = 7, but i don't need that id.

I need the id 4, because is the first (older) id from the last client.

I need a query from that result.

I use this query:

```
$re=mysql_query('SELECT traffic.*, client.alias FROM traffic INNER JOIN  service ON traffic.service_id = service.service_id INNER JOIN client ON service.client_id= client.client_id WHERE vehicle="'.$_GET['s'].'" AND client.alias = "'.$Days1.'" GROUP BY client.alias ORDER BY traffic.date ASC LIMIT 1');
```

My tables are:

```
mysql> select traffic_id, service_id, date, vehicle from traffic limit 5;
+-------------+-------------+---------------------+----------------+
| traffic_id  | service_id  | date                | vehicle        | 
+-------------+-------------+---------------------+----------------+
|     1057967 |     1106746 | 2012-01-02 06:35:23 | 2816           |
|     1057968 |     1106747 | 2012-01-02 06:35:55 | 2817           |
|     1057969 |     1106748 | 2012-01-02 06:36:11 | 48789          |
|     1057970 |     1106749 | 2012-01-02 06:37:27 | 48888          |
|     1057971 |     1106750 | 2012-01-02 06:37:59 | 48887          |
+-------------+-------------+---------------------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select service_id, client_id from service limit 5;
+-------------+------------+
| service_id  | client_id  |
+-------------+------------+
|     1106746 |          1 |
|     1106747 |          2 |
|     1106748 |          2 |
|     1106749 |          3 |
|     1106750 |          4 |
+-------------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> select client_id, alias from client limit 5;
+------------+------------+
| client_id  | alias      |
+------------+------------+
|          1 | EXPRESS    |
|          2 | CONWAY     |
|          3 | ACC        |
|          4 | GO         |
|          5 | ACCEL      |
+------------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What if two users share the MIN(date) (just as they share the MAX(date))

Comment: which users? or you mean clients

Comment: The important field is id, I need the MIN(id) from the last client, in this case is the id 4, not id 7. I don't really use the date

Comment: Add all your table schema as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "last" client? `MIN(id)` for the rows with `client = 'v1'` is `1`, not `4`.

Comment: Sorry I edit the id's. Now the last client is 'v1' because is the last id (id=7), but I need the first movement of that client. The movement for the client 'v1' begins in the id '4'. Ignore the id '7' because that row doesn't matter, is not continous.

Answer (score 1):

You can give this a try:

```
SELECT 
  cd1.id,
  cd1.client,
  cd1.`date`
FROM clientData AS cd1
  INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT *
    FROM clientData
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS cd2 ON cd1.client = cd2.client AND cd1.id != cd2.id
ORDER BY cd1.`date`
LIMIT 1;
```

Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5611/30).

Comment: The query looks great, this is my query:                       $re=mysql_query('SELECT traffic.*, client.alias FROM traffic

INNER JOIN service
ON traffic.service_id = service.service_id

INNER JOIN client
ON service.client_id= client.client_id

WHERE vehicle="'.$_GET['s'].'" AND client.alias = "'.$Days1.'" 

GROUP BY client.alias ORDER BY traffic.date ASC LIMIT 1');                  How I can put your query on my query. Thanks A lot.

Comment: @wearedoom Just replace `client` in your query with my query. I think this is what you need.

Comment: @wearedoom Better update your question and add all tables and some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

So, for instance...

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ) y
    ON y.client = x.client 
   AND y.id > x.id
 ORDER 
    BY x.id DESC 
 LIMIT 1;
```